# How to assign a pull-up/down resistor in Verilog for inputs?

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, pullup, pulldown

As a newbie in FPGA world, I realized that it is possible to set pull-up/down resistors in Verilog but I don't know how.

I have written my code that works just fine but when I connect my XC3S400 to AVR micro-controller, At the start-up time it does weird things. I thought to add pull down resistors to input ports but the code for pull-up/down is a kind of assignment that rejects inputs.For example in the Verilog (under Xilinx ISE Webpack 14.7) , when I write:

```
input   in1;
pulldown  i0( in1 );
```

I receive this error: " *Unsupported gate instantiation.* "

Is it possible to add pullup/downs to ***"Inputs"***?

Comment: I suggest you to try adding the pull up in the UCF file, the pin constraints file.

Comment: Thanks! That's a good hint. But which one is better: pull-up or pull-down?

Comment: Well, if you're using an open-drain NMOS, a pull up. If you're using an open-drain PMOS, a pull-down. If you don't have an open-drain device at your output, don't use a pull-up or a pull-down. Your problem lies elswhere.

Comment: It depends on what is the non-active level of your signal. If you have an active high input, it is better to have a pull down.

Comment: @cagrigurleyuk please leave your comment as answer that I can mark it as the correct answer. Thanks that helped so much.

Comment: http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/3377.html
check this out. they did something similar.

Comment: It also depends what your device supports. AFAIK Xilinx CPLDs don't have user controllable pull-up or pull-down resistors. The FPGAs I think have pull-ups, but can't remember if they also have pull-downs.